# Vuejs form get multiple value in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form which is showing multiple input based on database data and I need to get each **input `value` plus their `id`** when I submit my form.

The final result of this form when I send it should be something like this:

```
array:2 [
    0 => [
        id => 1,
        value => "123
    ],
    1 => [
        id => 5,
        value => "test"
    ]
]
```

currently what I get is this (only values):

```
array:2 [
  0 => "123"
  1 => "test"
]
```

## Code

```
<form ref="form" :model="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div
        class="col-md-6"
        v-for="(field, index) in fields"
        :key="index"
        >
        <input
            class="form-control"
            v-model="form.field[index]"
            :placeholder="field.title"
        />
        </div>
    </div>
    <vs-button
        class="mt-3"
        @click="onSubmit"
        native-type="submit"
        gradient
    >
        Generate
    </vs-button>
</form>


data() {
    return {
      fields: [],
      form: {
        field: [],
      },
    };
},
methods: {
     onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      axios
        .post("/api/admin/documents/add/", this.form, {...} // sending "this.form"
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: where should the id come from?

Comment: `fields` array as if use it in `v-for` -> `v-for="(field, index) in fields"`

Comment: so why would the id's be 1 and 5? surely they'd be 0 and 1 for two items - that's how arrays work

Comment: @Bravo what you talking about is `index` number not id, id of my data comes like `field.id` just like i have `field.title`

Comment: oh, so fields array has an id ... use that

Comment: then what will be the different? I want id as variable inside my `form.field` not as identification of `form.field` please just see my sample code that I'm looking for

Comment: yes, that's right, put the id inside the form.field

Comment: @Bravo that is exactly what i'm looking for, how?

Comment: @Bravo no idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this helps.

```js
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
     data() {
    return {
      message: "Vue 2",
      fields: ["First Name", "Last Name"],
      myForm: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myForm = this.fields.map((field, index) => ({
      id: index+1,
      title: field,
      value: ""
    }));
  },
  methods: {
    save(){
      console.log(this.myForm)
    }
  }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <div>
      <div v-for="(form, index) of myForm">
        <label>{{ form.title }}</label>
        <input :placeholder="form.title" v-model="form.value" name="index" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" @click.stop.prevent="save">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <p>{{myForm}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I think you've mixed up things a little bit. first of all my `v-for="(form, index) of myForm"` is not form based is databased based to I have dynamic data presented by `fields` array, second I really don't need to send `index` numbers but `ids` of my `fields` array something like `field.id` as of `v-for="(field, index) in fields"` any idea on that?

Comment: is this your field model =>  fields: [{id:1,title: "First Name"}, {id:4,title: "Last Name"}],

Comment: It needed a bit of adjustment for instance instead of using `mounted()` I had to place it in `then()` of my `axios` where I got `fields` array data.... but works for me now thank you.

Comment: hold on there is an issue, the form data isn't named, so i just get key numbers in my controller which makes it hard to deal with incoming requests and loop them, is there a way we put a name of this arrays instead of numbers? like I had `field: {...data here...}`

Comment: I can help you if you can provide sample code.

Comment: fixed it I put name on it in axios `axios.post(url, { fields: this.myForm }, {...});` so I can fetch it in controller